# Why aren't my Strings showing as equal when they are?

Tags: java, android

I am currently working in Eclipse making a Android App. At the moment I have two Strings and I need to check if they are equal or not, the problem is the Strings are equal but it is showing them not to be which is really frustrating me.

```
    if (newSource.equals(source)) {
        Log.d("Equal:", "Strings are equal");
    }
    else {
        Log.d("Not Equal: ", "Strings aren't equal");     
    }
```

When I run this it just prints in the log cat that the strings aren't equal. I have printed both strings in the log cat to check that they are 100% equal which they are. I was just wondering if any one could see an error in my code?
Thanks

Comment: Most likely, there's some subtle difference in the two strings. For example, one may have a newline at the end or one may have a tab where the other has a space.

Comment: leading or trailing whitespace maybe? print your strings enclosed in quotation marks and compare again.

Comment: In your log, print both strings for a visual comparison as well. If case does not matter use, .equalsIgnoreCase(String str).

Comment: can you show us how you print them to logcat?

Comment: please correct the code indention (Cannot be done by me, because change only contains space characters)

Comment: **tldr; this is not a bug with `String.equals`.** So, find out why the strings contain *different values* .. look at the slew of guess answers this lack of information has caused :-/ I have given a -1 for failing to provide example (well, any) inputs strings and/or a minimal test-case that can be reproduced.

Comment: *Why not show your strings?*

Comment: Hi I only asked if my code had any errors in "I was just wondering if any one could see an error in my code?", I didn't ask anyone to compare the Strings I can do that myself. I just wanted to know if the code was the correct way for comparing strings.

Comment: Please read a tutorial on Strings or see the API (i.e. `String.equals`) if that is your question. It is well covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `trim()`     which will eleminate spaces if any

```
if ((newSource.trim()).equals(source.trim()))
```

Answer (score 8):

Its because the strings aren't really equal. To see the byte representation of your strings, you can do

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str1.getBytes()));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str2.getBytes()));
```

Comment: Hi, I am making a Android app so unfortunately I cannot do System.out (Although I wish I could). Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @iputonmyrobeanwizardhat : how we compare these two values.because OP want to compare these value and perform some action according to comparison result

Comment: When I print these to the log cat both Strings show 22 lines of different numbers, 
e.g one line looks like
32, 102, 114, 111, 109, 32, 97, 32, 115, 111, 117, 114, 99, 101, 32, 119, 105, 116, 104, 111, 117, 
I don't understand how I am supposed to compare them..

Comment: My code was an example of how a programmer goes about *debugging*. When something doesn't work as they expect, a programmer *investigates* the reason. I gave you some code which allows you to see what your strings truely are, because some characters in strings are impossible to visually distinguish - but you can distinguish them by looking at the raw bytes. If they were equal, they would have identical bytes. Again, I never implied a method to make your strings compare as equal, I purely showed you how to SEE that they are different.

Answer (score 1):

try as using [String.equalsIgnoreCase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29)

```
if (newSource.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(source.trim())) {
      Log.d("Equal:", "Strings are equal");
   }
 else {
        Log.d("Not Equal: ", "Strings aren't equal");     
   }
```

becuase  it's possible string contains spaces,lower and uppercase letters

Comment: Because there is no equalsignorecase() method on the String class.  However, there is an equalsIgnoreCase().  Case matters in Java.

Comment: equalsIgnoreCase not equalsignorecase

Comment: I am going to leave my -1 in place, even after removing my now obsolete comment. Please make sure that *you read* that docs so as to avoid silly code that doesn't compile. (Compare the current version of the answer and the first version(s).)

Comment: I would prefer to fix the reason for the little string difference, eg. not clean splitting...no reason to make it case insensitive..

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K think about "equalsignorecase".equalsIgnoreCase("equalsIgnoreCase")

Comment: @duffymo : i read it and remember for next time to avoid this type of mistakes